# How to revert to old dataframe when removing newly added column?

Tags: r, dataframe

**Problem**

I have combined a large number of datasets into one dataframe. I then want to use that large dataframe throughout my code. However, at times, I want to only use one of the smaller earlier datasets but to do so with my existing large dataframe. I feel that it keeps my global environment tidy by only having one dataset.

Yet, whenever I remove the columns in the hope that my large dataframe would revert back to a previous dataset, it keeps all the rows as duplicates. See below for a sense of what I mean:

**Reprex**

```
# Dataframe 1

lawyer <- as.data.frame(letters[1:20])
clients <- as.data.frame(seq(1:20))
location <- as.data.frame(rep(c("urban", "rural"), 10))
df <- cbind(lawyer, clients, location)
colnames(df) <- c("lawyer", "clients", "location")

# Dataframe 2

clients2 <- as.data.frame(rep(seq(1:20),5))
prop_poor <- as.data.frame(rep(seq(0, 0.9, by = 0.1),10))
df2 <- cbind(clients2, prop_poor)
colnames(df2) <- c("clients", "poverty")

# Large dataset

df_final <- left_join(df, df2, by = "clients")
remove(df, df2)


# Trying to get back to Dataframe 1 (to build a graph, for example)

dfx <- df_final %>% select(-poverty)
```

In the above, I want dfx to return to the original df before I added the df2 to it. Yet, it still shows 100 rows. Any help would be appreciated.

**Note**

The reason for my approach is that I have many many datasets and my Global Environment ends up filling up. Instead, I combined them all into a nice large dataset and removed the other smaller ones so now my Global Environment is less crowded. I then want to use subsets in this large dataset to build graphs using ggplot2.

I'm not sure this is good practice, but I'd still like a solution to my problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In general there’s no way to get your original table back, since there’s simply insufficient information in the large table to restore it.

But if you know that the original data had no duplicates, you can simply remove those:

```
dfx <- df_final %>%
    select(-poverty) %>%
    distinct()
```